# jquery value in dropdown selected disable checkbox

Tags: jquery, select, checkbox, drop-down-menu

I am trying to use jquery to disable a checkbox when the selected value of the dropdown menu is anything other than 0. My problem is when I select the item with the 0 value the checkbox is being disabled and to get the checkbox to disable I have to select at least two or more values before it will disbale the checkbox.

An example of my code is here:

[example code at js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vsYB8/2/)

When the selected value is 0 I want the checkbox and drop down to be enabled and when the selected value is anything other than 0 I want to disable the checkbox. I also would like it to work whether I start from the first row, bottom, row, or middle row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it, if my understanding of your problem is correct:

```
$("select").change(function() {
    $(this).closest("td").prev().find(":checkbox").prop("disabled", $(this).val() !== "0");
});

$(":checkbox").change(function() {
   $(this).parent().next().find("select").prop("disabled", this.checked);
});
```

[Your updated fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/vsYB8/6/)

Comment: thanks it almost works. I also want to be able to disable the drop down when a checkbox is checked

Comment: @larry - I've updated the answer and the demo. Please have a look.

Comment: it works great. I tried adding a text box that will only appear when the selected value is one but I can only get it to work for the first drop down. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to insert the textbox relative to the current select element, for example `$(this).after("<input type='text'/>");` within the select change handler. You should read more on DOM tree traversal: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/

Answer (score 1):

Try this (it [works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/vsYB8/8/)):

```
$("select").change(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
      $checkbox = $this.parent().prev().find("input");

  if ($this.val() != 0) {
    $checkbox.attr("disabled", true);
  } else {
    $checkbox.removeAttr("disabled");
  }
});

$(":checkbox").change(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
      $select = $this.parent().next().find("select");

  if ($this.is(":checked")) {
    $select.attr("disabled", true);
  } else {
    $select.removeAttr("disabled");
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks that works too. If I wanted to add a text box to show/hid would I do something like: if ($this.val() != 0) {    $checkbox.attr("disabled", true);  $(":text").hide();
 } else if ($this.val() !== 1) {    $checkbox.attr("disabled", true);  $(":text").show();
 } else {    $checkbox.removeAttr("disabled");  }});

Answer (score 0):

That's because at the 'change' event, the value you get is before the change is actually finished, so the change that the user is making 'now' doesn't show until the next time the event fires.

You want to use something like onblur, onmouseup or onkeyup to be notified post-change that you want to change the property of the check box.